# Applescript break loop from handler

Tags: loops, applescript, handler

Is it possible på break a loop outside of the handler, from within the handler?

Like break this repeat form within one of the handlers/functions?

```
repeat
    set varChosenType to setsessionid()
    set varKlasseIDliste to readCSVfile(varChosenCSV, "KlasseIDliste")
    set varElevnavnIDliste to readCSVfile(varChosenCSV, "ElevnavnIDliste")
    set varChosenKlasse to ChooseKlasse(varKlasseIDliste)
    set varChosenklassenames to makelistChosenKlasse(varChosenKlasse, varElevnavnIDliste)
    set varChosenElev to chooseElevID(varChosenklassenames, varChosenKlasse)
    showChosenElev(varChosenElev, varChosenKlasse, varFolders)
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can return `missing value` in case of a failure and then exit the repeat loop

```
repeat
    set varChosenType to setsessionid()
    set varKlasseIDliste to readCSVfile(varChosenCSV, "KlasseIDliste")
    set varElevnavnIDliste to readCSVfile(varChosenCSV, "ElevnavnIDliste")
    set varChosenKlasse to ChooseKlasse(varKlasseIDliste)
    if varChosenKlasse is missing value then exit repeat
    set varChosenklassenames to makelistChosenKlasse(varChosenKlasse, varElevnavnIDliste)
    set varChosenElev to chooseElevID(varChosenklassenames, varChosenKlasse)
    showChosenElev(varChosenElev, varChosenKlasse, varFolders)
end repeat

on ChooseKlasse(klasseListe)
   -- do things
   if condition is true then return klasse  
   return missing value
end
```